# Sugarcrm: remove file on uprades via manifest.php

Tags: sugarcrm

How can I remove file on loading upgrade of some sugarcrm module?

I can write 'copy' in upgrade section of manifest.php to copy new file. But how can I remove old (useless) file upon install of a newer version of the same module?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the scripts/post_install.php script and insert the logic there to remove the file.

Comment: Suppose I have a file in ver 1.0.0 and want to remove it in ver 1.1.0. Will it be restored when i deinstall version 1.1.0?

Comment: You will need to use the post_uninstall.php script to do that dirty work. To be honest, most people just leave in the extraneous files as no harm is done by doing so.

Comment: Thanks for replay. In additional I'll try to post bug (request for new functionality?) to sugarcrm bug tracker. It'is not so difficult to do it, isn't it?

Comment: It's a dangerous feature to add so I'd expect reasonably that it would never get implemented. I could be wrong.

Comment: Why? One can check that file that to be removed is in previous version of module. And than I think using triggers is more  dangerous feature

Answer (score 2):

Any file that is installed via a 'copy' command should be automatically removed/replaced upon uninstall.  There are no further commands needed to make it work.  Backups of any files/directories that are replaced (if there are any) are kept in the upload directory.

Comment: I'd like to install new version of module without deinstalling previous version. I'd like to use upgrade section in manifest.php.

Comment: The question is to remove an existing file that is no longer needed and not the whole module. So simply uninstalling the module will not work.